# How can I get SQL query from repository?

Tags: magento-2.1

Lets asume that I have code like this:

```
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
    ->addFilter('increment_id', $incrementId, 'eq')
    ->create();

$orderList = $this->orderRepository
    ->getList($searchCriteria);
```

Is it possible to see SQL query in a way like it was done in Magento 1 with model object:

```
echo Mage::getModel('module/model')->getCollection()->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Comment: try this echo $searchCriteria->getSelect()->__toString();

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do the following -:

> print_r($orderList->getSelect()->assemble());

This will output the actual query with all where clauses and joins. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled about this question by trying to find out the same on v.2.2

Unfortunately the collection of a repository isn't public accessible from within objects using it. For me the best way - for now - was to use xdebug (https://xdebug.org/) and the corresponding watcher feature of my IDE (Intellj Ultimate => see https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). In my case I had done some filtering on the cms page repository and wanted to see the query, when it is done. 
I did this by adding a brakpoint in \Magento\Cms\Model\PageRepository::getList (161). 
When the debugger stopped there, I was able to watch the query using the watcher by adding the following expression to the watchlist:

```
$collection->getSelect()->assemble()
```

That is the known Magento 1 style. 
[image: Screenshot xdebug]

I hope this helps a little bit to get further. 
If someone wanted to know how to use xdebug with IntelliJ or PHPStorm, have a look at https://www.ask-sheldon.com/php-xdebug/.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that is because the order repository getList method returns a different object that isn't a collection ( \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderSearchResultInterface ).  This object returns a collection of orders inside a wrapper, with other details such as page number, total count, as well as a collection called items.

You need to create a sales order collection and then you can do

```
$collection->getSelect()->_toString();
```

The order searchResultsInterface has a getItems method - which returns an array of order collection items:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Api/Data/OrderItemSearchResultInterface.php

All of the collection processing is done in this class:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Api/SearchCriteria/CollectionProcessor.php

You might want to test if you can log SQL from here.

Comment: Yes you can do it in an old fashion way but I would like to have it from repository object just to check if my search criteria are the way I want them to be in SQL statement for example SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = 1 AND col2 = 2 OR col3 = 3 OR col4 = 4 etc.

Comment: Understood - I have provided more info for you to trace the way it works.